# Varargs error when using Parameterized class in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

I am creating a test case using the `Parameterized` class to improve scalability. I have something like the following...

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Test
{
    private final translator;

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "translate {0}")
    public static Collection parameters()
    {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { Translate.EN },
                { Translate.FR }
        });
    }

    public Test1(Translate translate)
    {
        this.translator = new TranslatorImpl(translate);
    ...
    ...
```

I have a Linter that is throwing an error for the following part...

```
return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        { Translate.EN },
        { Translate.FR }
});
```

It says...

> There's no point in creating an array solely for the purpose of passing it as a varargs (...) argument; varargs is an array. Simply pass the elements directly. They will be consolidated into an array automatically. Incidentally passing an array where Object ... is expected makes the intent ambiguous: Is the array supposed to be one object or a collection of objects?

I might have to add more arguments, and so using the `Parameterized` class is helpful and I would like to use that, but I am not sure how to resolve the issue that I'm getting and if it is even worth resolving. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: is it gone when you change it to `Arrays.asList(new Object[] { Translate.EN }, new Object[] { Translate.FR })`?

Comment: @AdamSiemion Nope, the issue remains. Same error, but it is being caused by the second Object definition.

Comment: a when you create method `Object[] m(Object a) { return new Object[] { a }; }` and change it to `Arrays.asList(m(Translate.EN), m(Translate.FR))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.asList`'s signature is `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)` So instead of feeding an array to `Arrays.asList`, you can feed it individual array elements. In this particular case:

```
return Arrays.asList(
  new Translate[] { Translate.EN },
  new Translate[] { Translate.FR }
);
```